# Como inserir um input type file com validação em um formulário Blazor (EditForm)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, blazor

Estou seguindo a documentação oficial **ASP.NET Core Blazor formulários e validação** neste link [Formulário Blazor com validação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1) e percebi que esta faltando alguns inputs, sendo estes:

- input type="email"
- input type="file"
- input type="image"
- input type="email"

Tendo somente estes

- InputText
- InputTextArea
- InputSelect
- InputNumber
- InputCheckbox
- InputDate

**Como usar os inputs input type="file" sendo que não tem no core do Blazor ?**

**Tenho o seguinte formulário que contém InputText, InputSelectNumber, mas preciso inserir um input type="image" ou type="file" como faço este procedimento ?**

```
<EditForm Model="@veiculo" OnValidSubmit="@Inserir">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label>Tag</label>
            <InputText @bind-Value="@veiculo.Tag" class="form-control" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => veiculo.Tag)" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label>Motorista</label>
            <InputText @bind-Value="@veiculo.Motorista" class="form-control" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => veiculo.Motorista)" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label>Placa</label>
            <InputText @bind-Value="@veiculo.Placa" class="form-control" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => veiculo.Placa)" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">

        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label>Empresa</label>
            <InputSelectNumber @bind-Value="veiculo.EmpresaId" class="form-control">
                <option value="0">-- ESCOLHA UMA EMPRESA --</option>
                @foreach (var item in empresas)
                {
                    <option value="@item.EmpresaId">@item.Nome</option>
                }
            </InputSelectNumber>
            <ValidationMessage For="@(()=>veiculo.EmpresaId)" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label>Tipo</label>
            <InputSelectNumber @bind-Value="veiculo.TipoId" class="form-control">
                <option value="0">-- ESCOLHA UM TIPO --</option>
                @foreach (var item in tipos)
                {
                    <option value="@item.TipoId">@item.Nome</option>
                }
            </InputSelectNumber>
            <ValidationMessage For="@(()=>veiculo.EmpresaId)" />
        </div>

    </div>

    @if (mode == MODE.Inserir)
    {
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Inserir</button>
    }
    else
    {
        <input type="hidden" @bind-value="@veiculo.VeiculoId" />
        <button @onclick="Atualizar" class="btn btn-primary">Atualizar</button>
        <button @onclick="Excluir" class="btn btn-danger">Excluir</button>
    }

</EditForm>
```

**Minha Model é esta**

```
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Código")]
    public int VeiculoId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Tag")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} é obrigatório.")]
    [StringLength(26, MinimumLength = 26, ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} deve ter no mínimo {2} e máximo {1}")]
    public string Tag { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Empresa")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} é obrigatório.")]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Preencha o campo {0} com valor maior que {1}.")]
    public int EmpresaId { get; set; }

    public Empresa Empresa { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Motorista")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} é obrigatório.")]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} deve ter no mínimo {2} e máximo {1}")]
    public string Motorista { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Placa")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} é obrigatório.")]
    [StringLength(8, MinimumLength = 8, ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} deve ter no mínimo {2} e máximo {1}")]
    [RegularExpression(@"[A-Z]{3}-\d{4}")]
    public string Placa { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Tipo")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} é obrigatório.")]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Preencha o campo {0} com valor maior que {1}.")]
    public int TipoId { get; set; }

    public Tipo Tipo { get; set; }
```

Comment: exemplo: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/341/uploading-files-in-blazor

Comment: Este "issue" tem informações relevantes: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/12205.